# How to display different input types(checkbox radio text) according to the user's preference in lwc

Tags: javascript, html, lightninginput, lightning-web-components

[image: App preview]

This is the current preview of my app where when i click a particular survey the corresponding question and answer is displayed.I want to modify the answers in such a way that answer type can be selected according to user's preference.The various choices available are checkbox,text,text area and radio button.How do i display it?

Code

**questionanswer.js**

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track, } from 'lwc';

export default class surveylist extends LightningElement {
    @api
    set surveyrecord(surveyId){
    qnSurvey({ SurveyId: surveyId })
        .then(result => {debugger
            this.quest = result;
            console.log('questions', this.quest);
        });
    }

    get surveyrecord(){}
    @track quest;
    @track error;
    @track AnsList;
}
```

**questionanswer.html**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Question with Answers">
        <template if:true="{quest}">
            <template for:each="{quest}" for:item="Question">
                <div key="{Question.Id}">
                    <p>{Question.Name}</p>
                    <template if:true="{Question.Answer__r}">
                        <template for:each="{Question.Answer__r}" for:item="Answer">
                            <p key="{Answer.Id}">{Answer.Name}</p>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </template>
        </template>
        <template if:true="{Anslist}">
            <template for:each="{Anslist}" for:item="Answer">
                <p key="{Answer.Id}">{Answer.Name}</p>
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**apexclass**

```java
public class surveylist {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) 
    public static List<Survey__c> qSurvey() {
        return[SELECT Name, Id FROM Survey__c];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Question__c> qnSurvey(Id SurveyId) {
       return [SELECT Id,Name, Type__c,(SELECT Id,Name,Question__c FROM Answer__r) FROM Question__c where Survey__c=:SurveyId];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hello Abhay, welcome to SFSE (Salesforce StackExchange). Could you please replace the screenshots of code (screenshots 2 to 4)? If possible it would be helpful for others that you show what have you attempted and where you got stuck.

Comment: @JefersonChaves Hi,I have replaced the screenshot images with the code.

Comment: Where are you storing the preferences?

Comment: @Victor Lockwood I tried to add the preferences in the html but got some errors and removed it.I don't have a clear idea about this.I want to display the text or checkbox or radio button as the option for the answers and include a save button so that when we click the save button all the details of the user including the survey's question answer are recorded.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to build? Do you face issues when you try to build a survey builder or a survey form?